# Divs are overflowing upwards with React mapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I'm building a small front-end app which has the screen split in the middle. I have an array of objects that I want to map out on the left hand side of the screen in the form of multiple div. So if you imagine that the array is of length ten, I would want the ten items mapped out and if they filled the screen, you would have the option to scroll down. The desired effect is something like this:

[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUE5l.png)

Where the grey bar in  the middle represents the scroll bar. I am able to successfully map over the array and render the divs, however they seem to be overflowing upward. What I mean by this is that first visible div is not displaying the first item in the array but some arbitrary part and I can't scroll upward anymore. This is what it currently looks like.(I can't scroll up past Div 7 in this case).

[Current Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exm47.png)

I'm assuming this is a CSS problem but I'm unsure of how to fix it. I'm not looking to use SCSS or any Node/React packages. I know the solution must be fairly simple. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

**My CSS code:**

```
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

**The component that lists out the array with divs** (simplified).

```
import React from "react";

const LeftComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="split left">
      <div className="centered">
        {props.myArr.map(({ id, name, dob}) => (
            <div
              onClick={(event) => props.handleClick(event, id)}
              key={id}
              className="block"
            >
              <p className="duty_text">
                {name} | {dob}
              </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default LeftComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why the overflow isn't working is because you didn't set a `height` of `max-height` explicitly on the container element.

According to MDN [Full reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

> In order for overflow to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (height or max-height) or white-space set to nowrap.

```
.left {
  left: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 300px; // as desired or max-height 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The issue

The problem is that you cannot really center the items by using `translate` or absolute positioning. It will somehow mess up the sizing of the div that has the `.centered` class attached. If you remove the `top: 50%` and the `translate` it will work, but the items cannot be centered.

### Workaround

For the layout, we can use `flexbox`. Flexbox provides `justify-items: center` and `align-items: center` that does the centering for us, normally. **Unfortunately, we cannot use these properties here**, because there is a browser-bug with the sizing of the scroll-able content. We can use `margin: auto` instead for the vertical and horizontal centering of the items.

**Fixed example using flexbox**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.split {
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  /* do not use justify-content */
  /* do not use align-items */
  /* do specify min- and max-heights for the container */
  max-height: 400px;
  min-height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.block {
  /* must be auto for centering */
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="split left">
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 2
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 3
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 4
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 5
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 6
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 7
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 8
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p class="duty_text">
        Child 9
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="split right">right</div>
</div>
```